# URL Schemes: open the devices do not disturb settings?

Tags: ios, url-scheme

Does anyone know where I can find URL Schemes?

I've been following a guide on Stack Overflow but the Schemes no longer seem to work

I wish to open the devices do not disturb settings.. I can open the main device setting with this Scheme

```
App-prefs:root=General
```

But the following does not work:

```
App-prefs:root=General&path=DO_NOT_DISTURB
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: All of those sorts of URL schemes are considered private api and using them will result in app rejection. You can only open your own apps settings

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11 but that didn't really answer my question.. This app won't be going onto the App Store to Private API isn't an issue